# Reading password protected XLSM file using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, xlsm

I am using the code below.

```
File pt_file_obj = new File("file.xlsm");
FileInputStream pt_inp_strm_obj = new FileInputStream(pt_file_obj);
POIFSFileSystem poi_fs = new POIFSFileSystem(pt_inp_strm_obj);
EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(poi_fs);
Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);
if(!d.verifyPassword("mypassword")) {
      System.out.println("Incorrect password!");
}
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(d.getDataStream(poi_fs));
```

I am getting runtime error on line `POIFSFileSystem poi_fs = new POIFSFileSystem(pt_inp_strm_obj);`

I don't understand what am I doing wrong...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:128)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:112)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:300)
    at ptaccess.PTAccess.main(PTAccess.java:20)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is password protected? Only the exception seems to be implying it's a regular non-protected XLSX-type file

Comment: Yes, the file is password protected. There is some problem related to POIFileSystem.

Comment: Looks to me like it's a problem relating to the user - POIFSFileSystem is being quite clear that you're giving it the wrong kind of file!